# Find text between tab (\t) as a delimiter

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I thought this will be simple, but can't find out how to do it.

**Scenario**

I have a single `.csv` file with `id_user`,`text`,`id_group` columns where each column is delimited by `tabs` such like:

```
"123456789"        "Here's the field of the text, also contains comma"        "10"
"987456321"        "Here's the field of the text, also contains comma"        "10"
"123654789"        "Here's the field of the text, also contains comma"        "11"
"987456123"        "Here's the field of the text, also contains comma"        "11"
```

How to find the the text?

**Attempt**

awk

I was looking for a way to specify the `print $n` delimiter, if I could do it an option will be

```
$ awk -d '\t' '{print $2}' file.csv | sed -e 's/"//gp'
```

where `-d` is the delimiter for the `print` option and the `sed` to take out the `"`

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374239/tab-separated-values-in-awk

Comment: Use `awk -F '\t' ...`.

Comment: @Thor please update your answer with this option to accept it, this is what I was looking for

Comment: @tachomi: Glad it worked, added two awk alternatives.

Comment: @tachomi: You could also use the double-quotes as the delimiter. See my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## TAB delimiter

#### cut

You do not need `sed` or `awk`, a simple `cut` will do:

```
cut -f2 infile
```

#### awk

If you want to use awk, the way to supply the delimiter is either through the `-F` argument or as a `FS=` postfix:

```
awk -F '\t' '{ print $2 }' infile
```

Or:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' FS='\t' infile
```

#### Output in all cases:

```
"Here's the field of the text, also contains comma"
"Here's the field of the text, also contains comma"
"Here's the field of the text, also contains comma"
"Here's the field of the text, also contains comma"
```

## Quote delimiter

If the double-quotes in the file are consistent, i.e. no embedded double-quotes in fields, you could use them as the delimiter and avoid having them in the output, e.g.:

#### cut

```
cut -d\" -f4 infile
```

#### awk

```
awk -F\" '{ print $4 }' infile
```

#### Output in both cases:

```
Here's the field of the text, also contains comma
Here's the field of the text, also contains comma
Here's the field of the text, also contains comma
Here's the field of the text, also contains comma
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `grep` with PCRE (`-P`) :

```
grep -Po '\s"\K[^"]+(?="\s)' file.txt
```

- `\s"` matches any whitespace followed by a `"`, `\K` discards the match
- `[^"]+` get our desired portion between two `"`s
- `(?="\s)` is a zero width positive lookahead pattern ensuring the required portion is followed by `"` and any whitespace character.

Example :

```
$ grep -Po '\s"\K[^"]+(?="\s)' file.txt 
Here's the field of the text, also contains comma
Here's the field of the text, also contains comma
Here's the field of the text, also contains comma
Here's the field of the text, also contains comma
```

Answer (score 2):

To specific the `tab` as a delimiter

```
$ awk -F '\t' '{print $2}' file.csv
```

To take away the unwanted `"`

```
$ awk -F '\t' '{print $2}' file.csv | sed 's/"//g'
```

Other option using `awk -F`

```
$ awk -F '"' '{print $4}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use perl for this, because `Text::CSV` is really good for handling non-trivial CSV (e.g. involving quotes):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

open ( my $input, '<', "file.csv" ) or die $!;   
my $csv = Text::CSV -> new ( { binary => 1, 
                               sep_char => "\t", } );

while ( my $row = $csv -> getline ( $input ) ) {
    print $row -> [1],"\n";
}
close ( $input );
```

Prints:

```
Here's the field of the text, also contains comma
Here's the field of the text, also contains comma
Here's the field of the text, also contains comma
Here's the field of the text, also contains comma
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sed part is correct. You can either use `awk -F '\t'` or the following,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {print $2}' file.csv | sed 's/"//g'
```

or if you do not want to use sed, you can pipe the output of the first awk to the second awk and then use '"' as the field delimiter and then print the second field.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {print $2}' file.csv | awk -F "\"" '{print $2}'
```